# Advice on creating a slim, rechargeable GPS tracker for watches with longer battery life

Tags: gps, programming-languages

I'm looking to create a GPS tracker that can be attached to a wallet or something, similar in function to an Apple AirTag but slimmer, rechargeable, and with a longer battery life. I'm wondering if anyone has any advice or recommendations for components or technologies that could help me achieve this.

Specifically, I'm looking for suggestions on:

GPS modules: What are some good options for GPS modules that are slim and power-efficient, but also accurate and reliable? Ideally, I'd like to be able to track the location of the watch in real-time.

Batteries: What type of battery would be best suited for this kind of device, given the need for it to be rechargeable and have a long battery life? Are there any particular models or brands that you would recommend?

Circuit design: What would be the best way to design the circuit for this kind of device, given the need for it to be slim and lightweight? Are there any particular components or techniques that would be helpful to consider?

Software: What programming languages or tools would be best suited for developing the software for this kind of device? Are there any particular libraries or frameworks that would be helpful to use?

Engineer: Where could I find engineers to build such a product?
Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Just want some feedback on the possibility of such an endeavor and some advice.

Comment: You are looking for some hardware advice whike this is a programming site. Try to post your question in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ or some other hardware site.